# Rename columns based on another DataFrame in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, names

My column titles are not correct. I want to rename all my column of a matrix (because i have v1,v2,v3,..) according to data frame (the name of the first column corresponds to the first title of my data frame). I have to repeat this for my 39 columns. So the goal would be to do a for-loop.

df1 is the matrix that has to be changed.

```
for (i in 1:39) {
names(df1[,i]) <- names(dfnorm[,i])
}
```

This code is not working.

Comment: You probably simply need `colnames` and the loop is not necessary. `colnames(df1)[1:39] = colnames(dfnorm)[1:39]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
names(df1)[1:39] <- names(dfnorm)[1:39]
```

Comment: hey! No it's giving me a dataframe with inside only one row which is the name of my 39 column.